Looped Regression and Inference in Stata or R
I have a sample of panel data and am running regressions on a loop for values of a specific categorical variable. For illustration:
$$ y_{it} = \alpha_i + \eta_t + \beta^C D_{it} + \epsilon_{it} $$
where $y_{it}$ is an outcome of interest, $\alpha_i, \eta_t$ are unit and time fixed effects, $D_{it}$ is a treatment dummy and $\epsilon_{it}$ is the error term. Suppose also there is a categorial $C$ variable with support in the set $\{1,2...,10\}$, and this regression is run for different subsamples based on the value of this variable (i.e 10 different regression are run).
After each iteration, I save the coefficients, standard errors and sample size for each regression. I then find the average of these coefficients giving me a single estimate (I do have my reasons for doing things this way). As a result, I have the variable:
$$ \tau = \frac{1}{10} \sum_{C=1}^{10}\beta^C $$
My problem is that I wish to derive standard errors/t-statistics for this average of regression coefficients. However, I am not sure whether it is easy to derive analytic expressions for this estimate or is it better to use the bootstrap? If the latter, could someone point me towards some resources in either R or Stata for doing this? I don't have much experience with this as it is, and the case seems somewhat non-standard.

Welcome to CV.  To get effective answers you will need to provide more information about what you're doing, the nature of the data, and your underlying probability model.

Hopefully, I have made things a little clearer. Do let me know if there is anything else I could add.
